# Add a class to the Immediate Parent Element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an element where it has a class creates dynamically. I want to add a new class to it's parent element if the child element has a specific class.

```
<a [ngclass]="addClassHere"> //need to add class here if child has a specific class
    <div [ngclass]="getScheduleDateColour(date.day)">{{date.day}}</div> //child class
</a>
```

the a element is created by the package and cannot access directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `getScheduleDateColour()` returns different names of classes, say 'childClass1','childClass2' and so on, and the required is 'childClass1'.
Now you can set a new class to your parent according to your child's class by :

```
<a [ngclass]="childDiv.className == 'childClass1'? 'ReqParentClass' : '' "> 
    <div #childDiv [ngclass]="getScheduleDateColour(date.day)">{{date.day}}</div> 
</a>
```

PS: If you want to add different parentClasses if child is not the required one, you can add it also in the ternary operator, like:  `'childClass1'? 'ReqParentClass' : 'ElseThisWillBeTheParentClass'`

Answer (score 0):

One of the options you have is to use [Template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)
for both your parent and child elements and change them pragmatically from your TS file
like so in html

```
<div #parentElem class="aquaDay">
    <div #childElem class="aqua">day</div>
</div>
```

and use `@ViewChild` to bind them and change them as you want

```
  @ViewChild("parentElem") parent: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("childElem") child: ElementRef;

  changeColour() {
    const childClass = this.child.nativeElement.className;
    this.parent.nativeElement.className =
      childClass === "aqua" ? "greenDay" : "aquaDay";
  }
```

I created a simple demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-422p1t?file=src/app/app.component.ts